# How do I connect the negative wire to three systems at different voltages?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc-motor

I have a system with three major components:

- throttle motor (powered by 48 V battery)
- steering motor (powered by 12 V battery)
- Arduino (powered by 12 V battery)

The 48 V, 12 V, and 12 V batteries are all separate batteries. I want to synchronize the ground of these three battery systems.

I am able to connect the negative for 12 V steering motor and the 12 V Arduino.

But when I connect from the Arduino ground to the motor controller's ground, which is the same negative as the 48 V battery, I will see spark, huge spark, and smoke....

Anyone know a possible solution? Here is a rough diagram:

[image]

Comment: Have you bolted or mechanically connected these items together in any way, or are they all sitting on the same metal table? It's possible that you've made an inadvertent connection somewhere in your system.

Comment: I would either contact the manufacturer or post a schematic and include make and model number. Why do you want to connect the grounds together. Check to see that they are all -.

Answer (score 2):

You can only choose your own common/GND if **all** components of all systems but one are isolated from each other, and from the machine chassis.

For instance the drive motor may have its negative (or its positive) tied to the chassis of the motor, and thus via metal to the steering motor, which may have its positive (or its negative) tied to its chassis.

For that matter, do you have opto-isolation between the Arduino and the motor controller?  I'm guessing not, I'm guessing you have wired control lines, and that control protocol sets a particular common.

It's also possible that your motor *is supposed to* be isolated, but actually has a ground fault to chassis.  That'll do it too.

You'll have to check documentation for everything and see how things are set up, and do some measurements on motors.

Comment: @greybeard I just switched OS versions and Safari Autocorrupt has not yet learned how I write.